# What do you call this kind of thing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What do you call this kind of dictionary inside an array thing?

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Category 1',
  children: [{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Subcategory 1'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Subcategory 2'
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Category 2',
  children: [{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Subcategory A'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Subcategory B'
  }]
}]
```

I understand that it is literally an array of objects, and how you would use it. I'm more interested in a conceptual/metaprogramming name for it.

So the ultimate question is, what would you *technically* call this, if you wanted to be as specific as possible while talking to another developer? Maybe a technical math term to describe it?

Thanks!

Comment: it looks like a tree.

Comment: So if you just had a bunch of those in that list, you'd just describe it as an array of objects?

Comment: In case you're wondering about the downvotes - they're probably for lack of research. Any beginner JavaScript tutorial will give you the answer to this

Comment: @Clive yeah I upvoted because I've never seen a javascript tutorial describe a metaprogramming in which each non-array object must be wrapped in an array when appearing in another object.

Comment: @Clive I've been programming for over a decade, and I've never really seen a tutorial explain what something inside of something is called. I know that it is literally an array of objects. I wanted to know if there was a name. Especially since an object can be so many things, but in this case it's a dictionary.

Comment: @Kenyon you may want to describe the specific thing you feel warrants a name regarding this object. I've been kind of guessing.

Comment: @djechlin I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: _I know that it is literally an array of objects. I wanted to know if there was a name._ That doesn't come across in your question (at least not to me). I read it that you didn't know what a `{` and/or a `[` signified. Might be worth clarifying that for the differently-brained like myself

Comment: @Clive fair enough. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Kenyon well do you mean the _outer_ thing, the inner thing, the `children` property? The whole construct as a whole (simplified `[{ "key": "value"}]` is simply an array with one object in it -> `[ ]` defines an array `{key: value}` defines an object . If you mean something else, please specify.

Comment: @vlaz OP is, I think, literally trying to find out if the pattern demonstrated in the question has a specific name, or an oft-used name that differs from "object", in JavaScript. You might be Overthinking it in my opinion Kenyon. But then I might be underthinking it

Comment: @Clive hopefully the updated question makes more sense now.

Comment: With your update - it's just an array of objects. There is no special name for it, really `[1, 2, 3]` would have been an array of numbers while `["a", "b", "c"]` is an array of strings.

Comment: @Clive yes, I probably am overthinking it since it in practicality doesn't matter at all what the answer is. I was just curious haha

Comment: Whether there is an _official_ name for it, which is more fancy than _**<data structure>** of **<member types>**_ I don't know but anybody should be able to understand what you mean if you call it that.

Comment: @vlaz that is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: it seems like you are asking if there is a special name for "array of objects." No, there isn't, this is just a ubiquitous idea in programming in any language. I don't even know anyone who would call it a pattern even.

The point of an array is that it can hold more than one thing of each kind. The inner array is an array of objects. It's called `children`. Children is plural. This is correct.

The outer array holds just one object. Perhaps the programmer intends to add more objects later. Perhaps it's being passed to a method that expects an array. I don't know, and it's not possible to infer anything besides "an array of one object."

Those are the only things even slightly unusual I see with your example. For how objects can hold arrays and how arrays can hold objects, consult any Javascript resource.

Comment: So I get what it is, and what it does. I just wanted to know if there was a specific term to describe an array of dictionaries. I'm not really concerned with the `children` part. Just imagine you had a dozen of those dictionaries repeated inside an array. Is the only term to describe that an "array of dictionaries" (if you wanted to be as specific as possible)?

Comment: But even if you wanted to be more specific and describe it to the 3rd level (i.e. children). I don't know if the metaprogramming "name" of the whole thing would change in that case

Comment: @Kenyon "dictionary" is more a Python-term than a JS one. It's just an "array of objects." This is ubiquitous in every computer program in any language and there is no further special name.

Comment: Hmm, seems like there would be a special name, but "there is no special name" is a valid answer to my question haha. I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) with nodes.

This object is a data structure to keep dependencies or relation of parent and their children.

A node contains `id`, `name` and `children`, which is an array and it can contain some more nodes.

The structure of a given node is

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Category 1',
    children: []
}
```

The given example has an array as root and this means the root have more than one node.

Comment: This is probably the most *technically* correct answer. At least from a mathematical standpoint. Thanks!

Comment: @Kenyon If the purpose of your question was to be able to find more information about how to use or model trees as a data structure, then this is the only useful answer.

Comment: @TimSeguine no, I literally just wanted to know if there was a special name for it. It didn't have anything to do with how or why I was using it. I just had to make a list like that for work, and it struck me to see if there was a special name for it while I was telling my co-worker that I had created <insert thing here> for him to use.

Comment: @Kenyon Okay, then you can tell him you created a tree for him. That's the name almost any programmer should understand.

Answer (score 0):

1. Everything in Javascript is an object.
2. This is an object of type Array that holds a set of objects, likely of type Object (default object type)

In a browser console:

```
> var x= [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Category 1',
  children: [{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Subcategory 1'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Subcategory 2'
  }]
}];

> typeof x;
// "object"

> x.constructor;
// function Array() {
//    [native code]
// }

> typeof x[0];
// "object"

> x[0].constructor;
// function Object() {
    [native code]
}
```

Comment: Huh, that's interesting having JS specifically output the types. Thanks!

Comment: Why are they "likely" of type object? How could they not be?

Comment: also might be interested in the instanceof operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: I meant likely of the formal type Object (capital O) :)

Comment: @GregoryPatmore again, what else would they be considering it's using object literal notation. Also `Everything in Javascript is an object.` not _quite_. `var x = 42, y = "abc", z= true` are three variables that hold primitives. Sure, you _can_ do, `x.toString()` giving the illusion that you're calling a method on the number 42 but behind the scenes JS is just silently wrapping the value for you. All other values would be objects, though. EDIT: A more accurate statement would be "Everything acts as an object" but it's a bit confusing, really.

Comment: @vlaz Not *everything* acts as an object, `null` and `undefined` for example.